Laravel Scout (database) doesn't recognise relations
I have an issue with Laravel (v11) Scout (using with database driver). Once I defined the models and the relations, the search doesn't have the relation.
These are the 2 models:
CourseCategory
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Laravel\Scout\Searchable;

class CourseCategory extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, SoftDeletes, Searchable;

    protected $table = 'course_categories';
    protected $primaryKey = 'course_category_id';

    public function searchableAs(): string
    {
        return 'course_categories_index';
    }

    public function courses(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Course::class, 'course_id');
    }

    public function parentCategory(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(CourseCategory::class, 'parent_category_id');
    }

    public function toSearchableArray(): array
    {
        $array = $this->toArray();

        return $array;
    }
}


Course
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Casts\Attribute;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;
use Laravel\Scout\Searchable;

class Course extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, Searchable;

    protected $table = 'courses';
    protected $primaryKey = 'course_id';

    public function parentCategory(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(CourseCategory::class, 'course_category_id');
    }

    public function searchableAs(): string
    {
        return 'courses_index';
    }

    public function toSearchableArray(): array
    {
        $array = $this->toArray();

        $array['category_name'] = $this->parentCategory->course_category_name;

        return $array;
    }
}


After I've made the models and everything was done, I did the Scout import:
php artisan scout:import "App\Models\Course"
php artisan scout:import "App\Models\CourseCategory"

When I trigger a search in the controller:
$res = Course::search('test')->get();

I get an error:
  "message": "Attempt to read property \"course_category_name\" on null",
  "exception": "ErrorException",
  "file": "C:\\......\\app\\Models\\Course.php",
  "line": xxx,

When I dd($this) in the toSearchableArray() in the Course model, the relations is empty:

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

From what I see, it looks like an eloquent issue related to relationship definition.
Open up a tinker shell and try to access a parent category from a course, for example: Course::first()->parentCategory, do you get a null?
